# Silex 2 - Provider needs another service not yet registered

Tags: php, silex

I have a service provider, that wants to call a method of another service from another provider, that is not yet registered. How can i solve this?

Let's say i have a service `$app["two"]` that has a `doStuff()` method. Then i have a service `$app["one"]`. During registration of `$app["one"]`, it's service provider needs to call the `$app["two"]->doStuff()` method, but since the provider of `$app["two"]` is registered after `$app["one"]`, that is impossible since silex doesnt know it yet.

The Provideder of `$app["one"]`:

```
class OneServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface {

    public function register(Container $app) {

        $app['one'] = function () use ($app) {
            $app['two']->doStuff(); // <- Error since not yet registered!
            return new OneService();
        };
    }
}
```

The registration part of the main app:

```
$app->register(new OneServiceProvider());
$app->register(new TwoServiceProvider());
```

In Silex 1, i think there was this `extend` method, which could extend/change a service when it is registered. In silex 2, i couldnt find anything similar. Is there any solution to it or should i dispatch an event in `$app["two"]` and subscribe to it in `$app["one"]`? Or should i use the `boot` method to call `$app["two"]`?

---

**Update**

I just tried the $app->extend approach. Sadly it still threw an error `calling member function doStuff() on null`

class OneServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface {

```
public function register(Container $app) {

    $app['one'] = function () use ($app) {
        $one = new OneService();
        $app->extend("two", function($two, $c){
            $two->doStuff();
        })
        return $one;
    };
}
```

}

---

**Solution**
Since i can no longer reproduce the original issue in clean test code, i'll have to assume that the problem was unrelated. Silex 2 seems to take care of this problem, no matter how you access services during their registration.
Tnx for your help anyways!

Comment: Silex and Pimple have been separated out a bit more clearly after Silex 1.x, so the docs for `extend` are in the Pimple docs, not the Silex ones. It still works the same though. http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/#modifying-services-after-definition

Comment: Ah! Many thanks, i didnt know those were two separate things. But you think i can call `$app->extend("two")` before it's registered?

Comment: I cannae recall exactly, and not in front of a "work" PC just now. But I think you register the dependency as per usual, then you `extend` it with the bit that calls the as-yet-unregistered dependency. the `extend` callback is not called immediately, so it doesn't matter it's not registered at "code time". But have not done this for a while. Have a play around, you'll likely work it out.

Comment: I just tried it. See Update above. it didnt work. It seems the extend method also needs execution of factory function already done. So i'm back to using Events or did i something wrong?

Comment: You cannot use `extend` like that because "In some cases you may want to modify a service definition *after* it has been defined". You could reference a non-registered service like that as long as that factory is not called before the second provider is registered -- after that is the point of having factory functions, they are not executed when you register them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is the lazy call. Don't use this :

```
$app['one'] = function () use ($app) {
```

but :

```
$app['one'] = function (Container $app) {
```

In the first one, the app don't have provider two.

**UPDATE**

It's working for me :

**TwoServiceProvider.php**

```
class TwoServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Container $app)
    {
        $app['two'] = function() {
            return new Test();
        };
    }
}
```

**OneServiceProvider.php**

```
class OneServiceProvider implements ServiceProviderInterface
{
    public function register(Container $app)
    {
        $app['one'] = function(Container $app) {
            $app['two']->doStuff();
            return new Test2();
        };
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
$app->register(new OneServiceProvider());
$app->register(new TwoServiceProvider());
$app['one']->doStuff();
```

Comment: I tried on my environment, it's working. Can you show the implementation of "TwoServiceProvider" ?

Comment: I'll try again in a real setup. My "fast check" might not have been enough. Many tnx s far. ;)

Comment: I just created a small test app to test your solution. I can not refactor my original app since i already changed it to events and don't want to loose that. Problem is: I can no longer reproduce my error, neither with my original approach nor with any provided solution. So in short: Silex works no matter how services call each other during registration. I'll check your solution anyways since it's probably how you "should" do it.

Comment: I think you have an other provider who is writted on a bad way